# Joining two streams from same spark streaming dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Is joining two streams coming from the same input streaming dataset allowed in Spark structutred streaming (2.3)?

For e.g. in the below example query, two streams are joined. 
I get IllegalStateException in the Azure eventhub spark client.

Is this expected to work?

```
eventhubs = spark.readStream ... .createOrReplaceTempView("Input")

spark.sql("SELECT temperature, time, device,  category FROM Input").createOrReplaceTempView("devices1")

spark.sql("SELECT temperature, time, device,  category FROM Input").createOrReplaceTempView("devices2")

val d1 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM devices1 WHERE device=0")
val d2 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM devices2 WHERE device=1")


val output = d1.join(
                        d2,
                        expr("""
                          devices1.category = devices2.category AND
                          devices1.time >= devices2.time AND
                          devices1.time <= devices2.time + interval 1 seconds
                          """),
                        joinType = "inner"      
                       )

display(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, semi join on Spark Structured Streaming allowed, but only in Append output mode.

Here's example:

```
class ExampleTest extends SparkBaseSpec {

  import spark.implicits._

  private val data: DataFrame = spark.range(1, 5).toDF

  data.write.parquet("/tmp/streaming/")

  val readStr = spark.readStream.schema(data.schema).parquet("/tmp/streaming/")

  val df = readStr
    .select($"id".as("id1"))
    .where("id1<50")
    .join(readStr.select($"id".as("id2")).where("id2<50"), $"id1" === $"id2")

  df.printSchema()

  val stream = df.writeStream
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/spark-streaming-checkpoint")
    .format("console")
    .outputMode("append")
    .start

  spark.range(20, 25).toDF.write.mode("append").parquet("/tmp/streaming/")

  stream.awaitTermination(30000)

}

root
 |-- id1: long (nullable = false)
 |-- id2: long (nullable = false)

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+---+---+
|id1|id2|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  3|  3|
|  2|  2|
|  4|  4|
+---+---+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+---+---+
|id1|id2|
+---+---+
| 22| 22|
| 21| 21|
| 23| 23|
| 20| 20|
| 24| 24|
+---+---+
```

By the way, you don't need create two temp views, just one is enough.

Hope it helps!